# Java Spring JPA repository with mariaDB generates invalid SQL

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am using MariaDB with Java Spring Boot. Driver is like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have JPA repository method like this:

```java
List<Plugin> findAllByPalpUrlStartingWith(
    String palpUrl
);
```

When app is run, it generates an incorrect SQL:

```sql
select * 
from remote_plugins p1_0  
where p1_0.palp_url like 'test' escape '\';
```

It is incorrect, because that quote char is escaped by the backslash and thus it is unclosed string.

I don't know what ESCAPE is supposed to do, MariaDB docs don't mention that, all I can say it obviously sucks at quote escaping.

Can I force JPA to generate correct SQL clause for `startingWith` use-case? Disable this ESCAPE thing completely, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The escape is automatically added because of MariaDB's implementation of the JDBC driver. According to the MariaDB [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#no_backslash_escapes), you may disable the escape using a different SQL_MODE.

Try adding it to your JDBC connection string, as follows:

```
jdbc:mariadb://host/db?user=xxx&sessionVariables=sql_mode=NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES
```

Comment: In the end I implemented query using JPQL instead of repository interface method and it works. Thank you for your answer anyway, might come in handy.